# FFprobe not showing frame's data

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, youtube-dl, ffprobe, yt-dlp

As a beginner I don't know much about ffprobe and other video editing command line tools. Please guide me here.

I am trying to download a video with yt-dlp and trim it to the nearest key-frame of my starting interval.

That is, lets say, I want "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZqWloHCjyY" this video from 00:04:30 to 00:04:40.

`yt-dlp -o "output.%(ext)s" -S "res,asr,+abr,+size" --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args "ffmpeg_i:-ss 00:4:30.00 -to 00:4:40.00 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZqWloHCjyY //to download the video`

After download I am trying to get some information about only the first frame,

```
ffprobe -read_intervals "%+#1" -select_streams v -show_frames "output.mp4"
```

But there is no output.
Now if I remove `-read_intervals "%+#1"` I am getting information all the frames.

Also I noticed if I use hard coded URL of video with this command,

```
yt-dlp -S "res,asr,+abr,+size" --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZqWloHCjyY
```

Then after I can get only the first frame data with previous `-read_intervals "%+#1"`.